# What could come next in this sequence?

Tags: pattern, visual

[image: pattern/sequence]

I found this on Twitter but no speculation until this point.

Comment: [Questions like these](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pattern+visual) usually come with a bunch of options/choices that we choose the right answer from.

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it.  If not, some responses to the answerers to help steer them in the right direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Could be something like this:

> [image: something]

Rationale:

> The short line gets rotated counterclockwise a few degrees each step, and one long line gets joined onto the existing line(s) for each step. At each step, the long line alternates between the "left" and "right" side of the short line. $$$$ The angles between the lines also get tighter with each step, but if they get much tighter it'll collapse into what looks like a single line; presumably not the intended solution.

Comment: But what about the whole thing is increasing by 2n+1 in every step? If we rotate the 1st CC certain degrees, a new line double the distance of the short is added. The 3rd is still CC rotate if the the 2nd but now there’s alternation for the new remaining short part that should be added, here it was added on the top long line instead of the bottom one.

Comment: the short line is on the wrong side in the third picture to meet your rationale

Comment: @JasonV, I'm thinking of the short line as the hand of a clock, rotating backwards, with a long line attached to the end of it. If you're standing on the end of the clock hand looking outward, first the long line is on your left, then it's on your right, and here it's on the left again.

Comment: @Leb_Broth, could be, do you get something like a star in that case (with a missing line, I guess)?

Comment: @Guest basically I never had an answer for that! But if you see the general rotating CC and growing in size (the growth is as such: the short line extended in double then deflects). Now the particular, there’s an alternation happening for where the short remaining line should be connected

Comment: @JasonV we can test this strategy: “the short part of the body is getting connected to an inward “hat” in every transition but the then the new added part is mirrored from the previous?